# reactJS array data does not render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code in a reactJS application to render some simple data:

```
    console.log("idArray: ", idArray);
    return idArray.map( item => (
        <div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12 text-left text_14">
                    <label> {item.fromFundName}</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    ))
```

This is what gets rendered and what is shown in the console.log():

[image]

At this point, I am just trying to get the fromFundName to display.  Any idea why nothing gets rendered?

This is the code of my render (for this running, this.state.transferState = 4 and this.state.indicative.functionUpdate = false):

```
render() {
    var transferState = this.state.transferState;

    if (this.state.indicative.functionUpdate == true) {      
        return ( 
            <Redirect to={{
                pathname: "/home",
                state: {
                    planName: this.state.passData.planName,
                    familyID: this.state.passData.familyID,
                    planID: this.state.passData.planID,
                    loc: this.state.passData.loc,
                    memberID: this.state.passData.memberID,
                    PIN: this.state.passData.PIN,
                    returnCode: "Your transfer request has been cancelled",
                    returnMessage: 'no fetch',
                    mqMessage: this.state.passData.mqMessage,
                    planMenuString: this.state.passData.planMenuString
                }
            }}/>
        )
    } 
    if (this.state.indicative.functionUpdate == "Cancel") {
        return ( 
            <Redirect to={{
                pathname: "/home",
                state: {
                    planName: this.state.passData.planName,
                    familyID: this.state.passData.familyID,
                    planID: this.state.passData.planID,
                    loc: this.state.passData.loc,
                    memberID: this.state.passData.memberID,
                    PIN: this.state.passData.PIN,
                    returnCode: "Your specific fund transfer has been cancelled",
                    returnMessage: 'no fetch',
                    mqMessage: this.state.passData.mqMessage,
                    planMenuString: this.state.passData.planMenuString
                    }
                }}/>
            )
    }

    if (transferState == "1") {
        return (
            <div>                    
                {this.renderSolicitFromFund()}
            </div>
        )
    }

    if (transferState == "2") {
        return (
            <div>               
                {this.renderSolicitFromPercent()}
            </div>
        )
    }

    if (transferState == "3") {
        return (
            <div>               
                {this.renderIntoFundAndPercent()}
            </div>
        )
    }

    if (transferState == "4") {
        return (
            <div>               
                {this.renderSolicitAnotherOrProcess()}
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {this.renderDefault()}
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

And this is the code in renderSolicitAnotherOrProcess():

```
renderSolicitAnotherOrProcess = () => {

    let currentComponent = this;  
    var localNumberOfFunds = currentComponent.state.numberOfFunds;

    var localData = {
        inv_FundAccurecordFundNumber: [],
        inv_FundMsgNumber: [],
        inv_FundName: [],
        inv_FundBalance: [],
        inv_FundAllocation: [],
        inv_FundPercent: [],
        inv_FundMinPct: [],
        inv_FundMaxPct: [],
        inv_FundTrsfInAllowed: [],
        inv_FundTrsfOutAllowed: [],
        stored_transfer: []
    }
    localData = currentComponent.state.data;
    var numberOfStoredTransfers = localData.stored_transfer.length;
    var trsfIndex = -1;
    var idArray = [];

    for (var l=0;l<numberOfStoredTransfers;l++) {
        var idObject = {
            fromFundNumber: 0,
            fromFundName: "",
            fromFundPercent: 0,
            intoFundNumber: [],
            intoFundName: [],
            intoFundPercent: []
        }
        var localCurrentTransfer = {
            fromFundNumber: 0,
            fromFundName: "",
            fromFundPercent: 0,
            intoFundNumber: [],
            intoFundName: [],
            intoFundPercent: []
            }
        localCurrentTransfer = localData.stored_transfer[l];
        idObject.fromFundNumber = localCurrentTransfer.fromFundNumber;
        idObject.fromFundName = localCurrentTransfer.fromFundName;
        idObject.fromFundPercent = localCurrentTransfer.fromFundPercent;
        for (var index=0;index<localNumberOfFunds;index++) {
            if (localCurrentTransfer.intoFundPercent[index]>0) {
                trsfIndex++;
                idObject.intoFundNumber[trsfIndex] = localCurrentTransfer.intoFundNumber[index];
                idObject.intoFundName[trsfIndex] = localCurrentTransfer.intoFundName[index];
                idObject.intoFundPercent[trsfIndex] = formatPercent(localCurrentTransfer.intoFundPercent[index]);
            }
        }
        idArray.push(idObject);
    }
    console.log("idArray: ", idArray);
    return idArray.map( item => (
        <div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12 text-left text_14">
                    <label> {item.fromFundName}</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    ))
}
```

Comment: do you have any CSS that could be interfering with this expected result?

Comment: Is no markup  produced at all?

Comment: do you receive any error in the console?

Comment: @DacreDenny - no.  This is in the middle of my application.  The css is being used prior to this code executing and it all works correctly.

Comment: @Rishav nothing is generated at all.  Just like in the screen print I provided.  very strange.

Comment: @Volodymyr no errors at all.

Comment: More information is necessary -- some things that come to mind: where is your target element that React will render to? Does one exist? If so, where are you telling React to render to it?

Comment: @hcs I have added additional code which I hope provides you with what you are asking.

Comment: Do you have something like this in your code somewhere?

`ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));`

And something like this in your HTML file?

`<div id="root"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using reacts [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html) prop. This will sanitize the string you're trying to render. Not sure if this is your issue but maybe worth a shot?

```
   <label dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: item.fromFundName}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I wasted everyones time.  It turns out my render was working the entire time.  I was rendering a single line of text (which is what I expected) but for some reason, the page scrolled down a bit so the rendered line of text was off the top of the page.  I added in my standard heading and I was able to see the rendered value